# Encode PHP array from MySQL to JSON

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, json

I've been trying to learn how to convert MySQL query results to JSON arrays in PHP and I haven't managed to make much progress.

Basically I'm trying to convert the results of this query into an array:

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT `status` FROM jobs");

   while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){ 

    $job_status = $row['status'];

   }
```

Into this:

```
$data = array(
  array( 'label'=> "a",  'data'=> 1), // The data values are queried using PHP and SQL
  array( 'label'=> "b",  'data'=> 2),
  array( 'label'=> "c",  'data'=> 3)
);

echo json_encode($data);
```

The $data array will be used display the values in the float chart. The code is shown below:

```
if($("#piechart").length)
{
    $.plot($("#piechart"), data,
    {
        series: {
                pie: {
                        show: true
                }
        },
        grid: {
                hoverable: true,
                clickable: true
        },
        legend: {
            show: false
        },
        colors: ["#FA5833", "#2FABE9", "#FABB3D", "#78CD51"]
    });
```

Below is the JS code that is converted into a PHP array and the encoded using JSON.

```
var data = [
{ label: "a",  data: 1},
{ label: "b",  data: 2},
{ label: "c",  data: 3},
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: how about `json_encode(mysql_fetch_array($sqljobs));` ?

Comment: in your sql you're fetching only 1 integer value/column for each row, how it even can be possible to convert it to 'label' or 'data'?

Comment: how `'label'`, `'data'` is related to `status`?

Comment: @IIya, I apologise for that, I've updated the code to show the correct example.

Comment: @Raja example is still incorrect and question is still unclear

Comment: Here is what you should worry about.  Figure out how to build the data structure (i.e. array, object) in PHP first.  That is all that is really important here, as the `json_encode()` is just the final step and trival once you have the data structured the way you want. So, in essence, your question might be "How do I populate all records returned by a query into a multi-dimensional array?". The json part is irrelevent. Also, if you are just learning PHP.  Please learn the proper way and use `mysqli` or `PDO` for MySQL database access. `mysql_*` functions should no longer be used.

Comment: @IlyaBursov I do apologise as I'm fairly new to the using encode JSON.  :) Essentially the data array will be store in a separate file (chartdata.php) and will be loaded every 10 seconds (setInterval) via jQuery AJAX to display the chart in (index.php). The values will be stored in the MySQL database.

Comment: how does `select status` turn into `label` and `data`?

Comment: @MikeBrant Thanks for your response! I'm still getting there but need more practice with the basics :) I've heard of PDO and I'll hopefully be using that very soon! That's right, I have to convert the query results into a multidimensional array and then encode it using JSON. Is it any different than converting it using standard strings vs query results? I assume that query results are also within an array which I guess is what confuses me...

Comment: @Raja do you really understand what I and Marc-b asking from you?

Comment: @IlyaBursov - I'm sincerely sorry as encoding in JSON and using arrays is fairly new to me. I've updated the question to include the full data that is converted into PHP and then encoded. Please do let me know what else you need. Essentially the problem that I have is loading the $data array using AJAX to fill the chart.

Comment: how 'label', 'data' is related to status?

Comment: @IlyaBursov - I assume they are currently not. As `status` is the result from the query, am I right in saying that $job_status will have to replace data? I'm not sure about the label...

Comment: so, ok, column `status` from query will go into 'data' field, but you have to know what strings should go into 'label' field

Comment: @IlyaBursov Ahh I see! I now understand what you were saying before :) The SQL query only returns 1 column. I should include the date as well in the query so will the date column will be replaced with the 'label'?  Thanks for helping out, I really appreciated it! :)

Comment: @IlyaBursov - I've managed to retrieve the row values from the query into the multidimensional array. The only problem is that the JSON request is not being passed through AJAX. The chart disappears. Would it be possible to point me in the right direction please? Thanks!

Comment: use browser's developer tools to check what ajax request are made (if any) and what returned, then check either client side or server side

Comment: @IlyaBursov - Awesome, Sure I'll give it a go. Thanks for all of your help, I really appreciate it :)

Answer (score 0):

mysql_fetch_assoc might work better